# / is not using my entire 30gb partition

Tags: partitioning, wubi

So I have some familiar background and experience with ubuntu such as adding repositories, installing drivers, installing packages and software like spotify and skype, etc. But that was on my laptop. Yesterday I wanted to add ubuntu on my windows 7 pc just for the kicks of dual booting. Before I would use wubi to install ubuntu I made a 30gp partition in which I would use to install linux on. I ran wubi and installed a 7gb installation of ubuntu on my 30gb partition. After installing I got into ubuntu 12.04, upgraded it to 12.10, 13.10, and 14.04(current) no problem. Then I started to install and update drivers. I installed spotify and skype no problem, however when I went to install steam I recieved an error which stated(Steam needs at least 250mb to update). I thought to my self "Wow that's weird, there is no way I used up 30gb already". I passed it off as a bug.

However rebooting ubuntu I noticed spotify was gone and when I started it up it failed to load. I rebooted again and went over to windows 7 and saw that a huge portion of memory was still empty and free space. Once I got back into ubuntu I saw that the space being used for ubuntu only has 6.8gb used. I don't understand, I thought I had a partition of 30gb and it isn't picking it up? Could someone please help me with a solution? Thanks!

when I use df -h in the terminal the following appears:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      6.4G  6.4G   39M 100% /
udev            5.9G   12K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  1.4M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda2        35G  7.0G   29G  20% /host
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            5.9G  340K  5.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   64K  100M   1% /run/user
dinoc@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      6.4G  6.3G   63M 100% /
udev            5.9G   12K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  1.4M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda2        35G  7.0G   29G  20% /host
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            5.9G  692K  5.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   64K  100M   1% /run/user
```

P.S sorry for the long desc. I somewhat feel that the 7gb installation has to do with why 6.8gb is fully used and not the entire partition.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: df -h Thanks.

Comment: The last supported version of wubi is 12.04. And if willing to partition, much better to do a full install. But you set the size of wubi in the install and that is just a file root.disk inside the NTFS partition. In wubi the size is the size of root.disk not the partition. You may be able to resize root.disk up to 30GB, but still better to have a full partitioned install. update bcbc beat me to it by 7 secs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Wubi works. It assumes that the host partition is being used by Windows and doesn't try to use its remaining space. Imagine if it filled up a regular partition and then Windows couldn't boot...

So the fact that you installed on a dedicated partition is lost on Wubi. You specified a root.disk of 7GB and that's all you get.

If you went to the trouble of creating a partition, then usually a normal dual boot is more suitable - in this case it would use the entire partition.

Otherwise, you could tell Wubi to use 30GB - but the whole point of Wubi was not to have to partition, and since you've already done that, I'd go for the direct install.

**Extending the size of the root.disk**

Or you can extend the root.disk to take more of your partition, by using this guides:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk

Please note that I've personally tested the first method, but not the second (the Live resize), but I've seen a couple of posts that indicate it works. There is no edit checking so you'd have to be very careful with it.

You can do the safer duplicate and resize method, but that will definitely limit you to about a 23GB root.disk: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could it be possible to extend root through a piece of software such as GParted?

Comment: @DinoCalandra I've edited my answer; Gparted won't work on the root.disk but there are other techniques.

Comment: I just used your script. And it worked! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @DinoCalandra great! Just a word of caution with Wubi use, maintain good backups and refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Warning